# Github and remote Git repo with production and development code

Tags: git, github, gulp, devops

I have my local Git repo which I push and pull to Github with my team as a central repo.

I then have a remote staging area which has the whole bare repo and post-receive hook to push my changes to the web. I use 'git push staging master' for this which puts site to staging area.

My project consists of a `src/` directory which I use to store my gulp files and sass files. I then use gulp to compile and produce my `dist/` directory.

I obviously don't want my `dist/` stuff in the Github repo as this causes crazy conflicts and doesn't need to be there, but **I do want** it in my remote website repo for production. How do I go about doing this?

I've looked at setting up separate `.gitignore` files for each remote, but this doesn't make sense as it almost defeats the point of Git, and I also don't think it's even an option after I googled a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*While your question is a little broad, here's a baseline you could start off of.*

You want to always ignore the `dist` directory and make the server (staging or prod) trigger a `npm install` after it has checked out the latest version.

Also, if you are using [**yarn**](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) or npm v5, commit the `yarn.lock` or [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) file that it generates.

Then, make it trigger your `gulp build` with npm's `post-install` hook.

You could also use [**husky**](https://github.com/typicode/husky), a npm module which automatically installs itself in the `.git` directory, letting you define and version git hooks based on commands in the `scripts` attribute of the `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "postcheckout": "npm install", // <-- Git hook from Husky
  "postinstall": "gulp build"    // <-- default npm hook
}
```